# Calculate arc length knowing its subtended chord and circumference diameter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

how do I calculate an arc length knowing only its subtended chord and the circumference diameter? I don't know the angle between OA and OB.
[image: Problem image]
Yesterday I did an experiment and calculated that the diameter / arc ratio is an exponential function
which tends to 1 when lowering the numbers.
My data:
d / a
20 / 31.6
19.5 / 26.4
17.5 / 21.4
13.5 / 14.4
10 / 10.2
5 / 5
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle O-A-B is defined since we know AB and OA = OB = 0.5*CD. Calculate the angle using the Law of Cosines ([see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)):

[image]

Therefore

```
angle = arccos(((0.5*CD)^2 + (0.5*CD)^2 - AB^2) / (2*0.5*CD*0.5*CD))
angle = arccos((0.25*CD^2 - AB^2) / (0.5*CD^2))
```

Then you can compute the arc length using the angle

```
arc = pi * CD * angle / 360°
```

Comment: Thanks to both, it was pretty simple at the end...

Comment: Thanks to both, it was pretty simple at the end...                     draw an isosceles triangle with two sides of 124 and the smaller one of 32. Then divide the smaller side by two to get two right triangles. The hypotenuse is sqrt(124^2-16^2) = 122.96. The inner angle is arctan (122.96 / 16) = 7.42. Remember I divided the first triangle in two right triangles? Well, we should double 7.41 to get the angle of the arc, = 14.83. We can finally calculate the arc with [Arc = ( angle * radius * pi ) / 180 = 32.1! That's how I did thanks to your inputs!

Comment: There's a mistake in your algebra, going from the second to the third line.

Comment: Yes, the hypotenuse is 124, the longer chatetus is 122.96 and the shorter chatetus is 16. Sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 5):

arc = CD asin(AB/CD)

(where the angle returned by asin is in radians)

**EDIT:**

I thought the derivation was obvious, but maybe I should explain it.
Mark the midpoint of **AB**, call it **E**.
sin(**AOE**) = (**AB**/2)/r where r=CD/2
angle = 2 asin(AB/CD)
arc = r angle = CD asin(AB/CD)

Comment: I agree, probably the simplest solution.

Comment: I created an account on this site solely to thank "Beta" (first answer below question). However, being a new account, I haven't earned the "points"/right to comment or even Up-vote. So, this comment is to confirm for others the accuracy of his/her answer. I can confirm (using my CAD program) his/her arc length formula is accurate to at least 10 digits right of decimal point (far more precise than any tape-measure). I spent over an hour combing google/bing for a simplified answer. The vast majority of searches resulted in people seemingly wishing to demonstrate their superiority with overly com

Comment: plex responses. His/hers was the first I came across that didn't involve an extra 10 lines of code. Thank you, Beta!

How I use it: I frequently have to fit rails to an existing layout. The only dimensions I can take on-site are chord and offset (in geometry terms: height). Previously, in order to quote the job (which involves arc length) I needed to use my CAD program. Thanks to Beta's condensed formula I can quickly total the equivalent linear lengths for quoting without creating a CAD file. (continued from the answer post)

Comment: @WroughtIronGuy: You made my day. And now my hat's too tight...